The meaning/motivation of "generator" of a $C_0$ semigroup
I am currently studying $C_0$ semigroups and have come across the term infinitisimal generator. Now I'm just wondering why it's called a generator and what it generates? Can we get to the semi-flow $T$ with it? It might also help me if someone could give me the motivation behind it, as I know a few applications but don't know exactly why it's "special" now.

This is a generalization of the concept of the infinitesimal generator of a one-parameter subgroup, which you should study first: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-parameter_group

The infinitesimal generator $A$ of a $C_0$-semigroup, $T$, is an operator defined in the following way:
$$Af = \lim_{h\to 0^+}{\frac{T(h)f-f}{h}}$$
The infinitesimal generator can be thought of as an operator that 'generates', as its name suggests, the $C_0$-semigroup. For example, if we take any bounded operator $A:X\rightarrow X$ as the infinitesimal generator of some $C_0$-semigroup, it generates a uniformly continuous semigroup (a classification of $C_0$-semigroups), $T$, in the following way:
$$T(t) = e^{At}$$
Although I am not sure if this is the exact motivation for the notion of infinitesimal generators, it makes sense to say that it is because studying them allow for a better understanding of the $C_0$-semigroups they generate, since they are so closely related.
Additionally, the concept of infinitesimal generators is also important to the study of PDEs, particularly that of abstract Cauchy problems, since it is known that:
$$
\begin{cases}
\dot{f}(t) = Af(t)\\
f(0)= f_0
\end{cases}
$$
has the solution:
$$f(t) = T(t)f_0$$
where $T$ is the semigroup generated by the operator $A$.
I hope that this provides an insight into the concept of infinitesimal generators of $C_0$-semigroups. Here is a nice resource that gives a more detailed overview on the properties of infinitesimal generators and $C_0$-semigroups, if you are interested: https://www.uibk.ac.at/mathematik/na/isem/isem15_lecture2.pdf
